# og meta tags, social buttons and angularjs

Tags: facebook, angularjs, facebook-opengraph

I'm creating a website using multiple views.
The  tag and the  tags of the page get changed through a a $rootScope variable.
so I have something like

```
<html>
<head>
   <title ng-bind="page_title"></title>
   <meta property="og:title" content="{{page_title}}">
</head>
```

Whenever each view get loaded on the website, the page_title variable changes and the title and the og:title tags get updated (everything works as expected).

The problem is that I need, on some views to load a facebook, a google+ and a twitter button.
I can display them properly but if I click on each them the page title appear to be something like:

```
{{page_title}}
```

I've tried to delay the execution of the scripts of each button using setTimeOut but to no good.
But the scripts just read whatever is written, they don't parse the page_title.

Does anyone know a workaround to this?

Thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This can't be done using javascript. Some people think that Facebook is reading what's currently on the page. It's not. It makes a separate request to your server using the same url (from window.location.href) using it's Scraper, and the Facebook Scraper does not run javascript. That's why you get {{page_title}} when clicking on something like a Facebook share button. Your content will have to be generated by the server so when Facebook goes to hit the url it gets the content it needs up front without the need for javascript. You can tackle the server side rendering in a fews ways.

1. You can allow your server side technology to render the content.
2. You can use the PhantomJS approach https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo.

Comment: Check http://prerender.io/, it is also based on phantomjs but seems to support multiple js frameworks and server platforms like node, java or php.

Comment: I've outlined a simple implementation of Earl's first suggestion (server-side rendering) in an article here: http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app/

Answer (score 1):

There's also a possibility that you can re-render Facebook widgets. Use their *parse* method:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

after your angular stuff has completed. It's not working for my share button (yet!!), but I tested it on likes, and it's cool. Basically it re-scans the DOM and renders the Facebook widgets. You can also pass it a single element, something like this directive:

```
'use strict';    
angular.module('ngApp')
.directive("fbLike", function($rootScope) {
    return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        if (FB && scope.$last) {
            FB.XFBML.parse(iElement[0]);
        }
    };
});
```

This snippet would rescan the DOM for html5 facebook fb-like widgets when creating the last element in angular repeater.