# Does facebook crawler need ajax prerender pages

Tags: angularjs, facebook, share

Having a website in angular JS, google is able to parse the interpreted content.

But sharing a link with facebook, is the facebook crawler also able to parse the interpreted content, or must we provide static pages (with eg prerender.io)?

Answer (score 0):

You must provide static pages, the Facebook crawler does not run JavaScript. Dynamic Open Graph tags are not possible.

More information: [og meta tags, social buttons and angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127980/og-meta-tags-social-buttons-and-angularjs)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any idea whether 'google structured data' (testable on https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) is also supposed to parse ajax content ? Asking it because I can't make it work

Comment: i guess not, i would not count on it. always make sure that open graph and metatags in general are NOT dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

You need  serve your page using `escaped_fragment` in your url. Either Twitter or Facebook bot don't know how to crawl Javascript content.

There are several service to do that, the most common is [prerender](https://prerender.io). If you want to do it by yourself, here is a solution [SEO for AngularJS](https://builtvisible.com/javascript-framework-seo/)